# Ruby On Rails - Rake schema - Max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, schema, innodb, max

Im trying to rake db:schema:load but I get the error

```
Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
```

From what I understand is that InnoDB only allows a max of 767 bytes in their index... And if you're using utf-8 it should be divided by 3.

But when i try to set a maximum of 100 characters (its not even close to 767) in the schema.rb the error still occurs...

**schema.rb**

```
add_index "friendly_id_slugs", ["slug", "sluggable_type"], :name => "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type", :unique => true, :length => { :name => 100, :slug => 100, :sluggable_type => 40 }
```

**Error**

```
-- add_index("friendly_id_slugs", ["slug", "sluggable_type"], {:name=>"index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type", :unique=>true, :length=>{:name=>100, :slug=>100, :sluggable_type=>40}})
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type` ON `friendly_id_slugs` (`slug`, `sluggable_type`)
```

**MySQL**

```
Your MySQL connection id is 1838
Server version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1-log (Ubuntu)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

- The `limit` parameter should be called `length`
- On multi-column indexes the `length` parameter should be a hash that specifies the length for both columns: `:length => { :slug => 200, :sluggable_type => 30 }`

Check out the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index-label-Creating+an+index+with+specific+key+length.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that didn't help, see my updated question with the new string. Thanks!

Comment: I added :Name and set the 

t.string   "slug",                         :null => false, :limit => 100

In the creation of that table to 100 and it worked but now I'm stuck with another error... Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah now it worked flawless! Thanks!

The solution is like you said slug => xxx, :sluggable_type => xx and set the :name with a limit when created the table 'friendly_id_slugs'

Comment: In Rails 5, you can simply use  add_index('table', 'column', length: 10)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using mysql 6, one utf char can be 4 (!) bytes.

but more importantly i do not think `add_index` supports `:limit`. It does however support `:length`
for column-wise char lengths limits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my MySQL is 5.5.x and I've added the length parameter but it doesn't help.